# Problem with JavaFX and Apple M1 (Silicon) Chip and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, apple-m1

> **Update:** After several trials I figured out a
> *workaround* to get this JavaFX / Apple M1 (Silicon) / Eclipse
> problem: When installing Eclipse 2021-09, use JRE 17.0.0,
> https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release/17.0.0,
> in the installer form for the Java 11+ VM specification.
>
> With this JRE at hand, the JavaFX application can be started
> successfully from within Eclipse. Changing the project's
> JRE back to another Java 17 JRE, however, still yields the
> problem described below.

I report here another problem I have encountered when running a JavaFX 17
application from within Eclipse on a brand-new Apple M1 (Silicon) based
laptop.

Executing the simple Hello World app from within Eclipse (right-click
class App / Run As / Java Application) yields the following stack trace:

```
Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/due1/.openjfx/cache/17.0.0.1/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/due1/.openjfx/cache/17.0.0.1/libprism_es2.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/due1/.openjfx/cache/17.0.0.1/libprism_es2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/due1/.openjfx/cache/17.0.0.1/libprism_es2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
...
```

Inspecting the user's cache for JavaFX shared libraries yields:

```
due1@host 17.0.0.1 % file * 
libglass.dylib:       Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
libjavafx_font.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
libprism_es2.dylib:   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
libprism_sw.dylib:    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Clearly, files `libprism_es2.dylib` and `libprism_sw.dylib` are not one for
the required M1 chip architecture.

However, if executed via Eclipse's Maven command, the application can be executed:

```
...
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:run (default-cli) @ hellomvn ---
[INFO] Toolchain in javafx-maven-plugin null
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Having imported the project into IntelliJ 2021.2.x, the simple application
can be executed. Then, the user's cache for JavaFX shared libraries looks like:

```
due1@host 17.0.0.1 % file *
libglass.dylib:       Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
libjavafx_font.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
libprism_es2.dylib:   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
```

And it seems that file `libprism_sw.dylib` (see Eclipse case) is not used.

Any clue?

Comment: Update: The Maven project can be found here: https://gitlab.com/edubuis/btx.prog.one.hellomvn.

Comment: When you run from Eclipse, where do you get JavaFX dependencies from?

Comment: This is not a JavaFX framework bug reporting forum. If you wish to report a bug against JavaFX, please search for the appropriate procedure to do so and do that.

Comment: @José Pereda: From Maven Central. (Of course, when downloaded, the JavaFX dependencies will be taken from the local Maven repository.)

Comment: @jewelsea: Thank you, will do. However, I‘m still not sure whether this is really a JavaFX issue.